# TeX capacity memory exceeded error

Tags: errors, captions

```
\caption[$Set\:3$: Intermediate set]{$Set\:3$: Intermediate set; Classical orifice plate ($s3c$); Plate numbers ($s3f(0-3)$); Classical plate,($s3p$).}
```

Is this a wrong caption? Because it is prompting an error as follows pointing at the line number of this caption:

```
Tex capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size 1500000].
```

Comment: Is it a very big document? I would write `Set $3$` anyway, but surely that's not the culprit.

Comment: It compiles fine for me. Could you turn your code snippet into a minimal compilable file that reproduces the error?

Comment: Yes, the document is indeed very big. Surprisingly, building in texshop, no error is produced unlike texniccenter.

Answer (score 3):

I build a minimal example with your fragment. It works fine whether I load `hyperref` or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption[$Set\:3$: Intermediate set]{$Set\:3$: Intermediate set; Classical orifice plate ($s3c$); Plate numbers ($s3f(0-3)$); Classical plate,($s3p$).}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Small tip: you can't use math expression in bookmarks. You will get the warning:

```
Token not allowed in a PDF string
```

To avoid this use:

```
\texorpdfstring{<expression in text>}{<expression in bookmark>}
```